# System taking unlimited inputs

Tags: java, string

The system is taking unlimited inputs when i run the code for the following program:

> Write a program to input a string.  Print the new string after reversing each word at its own place.
>
> Sample input: This IS a progRAM
>
> Sample output: sihT SI a MARgrop

This is what i have done so far:( in BlueJ IDE)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class revword{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        int i=0;//loop variable initialisation
        String temp="";//temporary variable which stores each word
        char ext;//stores character at each iteration
        String rev="";//stores the reversed string present in temp
        String sen="";//stores the new string 
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);//creating object of Scanner class
         System.out.println("Enter a string");
         String str=sc.nextLine();
         str=str+" ";//adding space after the last word stored in str
         for(i=0;i<str.length();i++){//for loop starts here
             ext=str.charAt(i);//extracting character present at ith index of str
             if(ext!=' '){
                 temp=temp+ext;//storing characters other than whitespace
                }
                else{//this condition works when character extracted from str is not whitespace
                    for(i=temp.length()-1;i>=0;i--){//loop for reversing each word
                        rev=rev+temp.charAt(i);//reversing the word pesent in temp
                    }
                
            temp="";//reinitialising variable temp
            sen=sen+rev+" ";//new string gets concatenated with each word and a space
            rev="";//reinitialising variable rev;
        }
    }
        System.out.println("The new String is "+sen);
    }
}
```

The program is getting compiled successfully. However after inputting a string, the system wants to take input for more strings. The situation looks like this:

[Snippet shows that the cursor is still blinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSiLW.png)

I am being able to give as many inputs i want but the final string which should be displayed on the screen is not showing up. The system is only taking inputs.
What mistake have I done?

Comment: Use a diiferent variable for the inner and outer for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of code

```
for(i=0;i<str.length();i++){//for loop starts here
         ext=str.charAt(i);//extracting character present at ith index of str
         if(ext!=' '){
             temp=temp+ext;//storing characters other than whitespace
            }
            else{//this condition works when character extracted from str is not whitespace
                for(i=temp.length()-1;i>=0;i--){//loop for reversing each word
                    rev=rev+temp.charAt(i);//reversing the word pesent in temp
                }

        temp="";//reinitialising variable temp
        sen=sen+rev+" ";//new string gets concatenated with each word and a space
        rev="";//reinitialising variable rev
    }
```

You are using same variable `i` for both the loops. Just use new variable for another loop. The variable `i` gets re-initialized in else block and hence the loop is not going to stop

Answer (score 0):

You have used the same variable for the inner and outer loops.
So the program won't work as intended

```
import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    class revword{
        public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
            int i=0;//loop variable initialisation
            String temp="";//temporary variable which stores each word
            char ext;//stores character at each iteration
            String rev="";//stores the reversed string present in temp
            String sen="";//stores the new string 
             Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);//creating object of Scanner class
             System.out.println("Enter a string");
             String str=sc.nextLine();
             str=str+" ";//adding space after the last word stored in str
             for(i=0;i<str.length();i++){//for loop starts here
                 ext=str.charAt(i);//extracting character present at ith index of str
                 if(ext!=' '){
                     temp=temp+ext;//storing characters other than whitespace
                    }
                    else{//this condition works when character extracted from str is not whitespace
                        for(int j=temp.length()-1;j>=0;j--){//loop for reversing each word
                            rev=rev+temp.charAt(j);//reversing the word pesent in temp
                        }

                temp="";//reinitialising variable temp
                sen=sen+rev+" ";//new string gets concatenated with each word and a space
                rev="";/reinitialising variable rev
            }
        }
            System.out.println("The new String is "+sen);
        }
    }
```